# Android/ios async notification using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, push-notification

I'm building an app using cordova most likely Android/ios. My app need to send a reminder to the user and ideally that notification would bring the user to the app. The app might and is most likely not running when the notification kicks in. The next notification is knows by the app in advance and does not need Internet to find the content of the notification. Currently the data is in localstorage so might not be accessible by native code ?

The way I see it would be a cron job running everyday at a specific (configurable) hour, then notify the user if it has to.

I wonder what is the best way to achieve this. Here's what I've found so far:

- Dialog/notification plugin in cordova, but that seems to kick in only when the app is running.
- Push notification plugin : from a first sight perspective, this seems to be Internet pushed notification and not really what I need.
- Specific code for different platform. In Android : a service using an AlarmManager to kick in at the right time and send a Notifications when necessary. This would need access to the localstorage in native code, or store the data elsewhere and is platform dependant, but looks like the only solution so far.
- Something else ?

What is the best solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this plugin. **[Katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)** It runs locally, so no internet dependency. Can repeat itself monthly, weekly, daily etc. Notification can be given when app is closed.